# Wordpress Nav Tab Items Add Filter function to return array with new tab

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, filter, hook

I have a settings page in my plugin which has multiple tabs generated like so:

```
private function get_settings_nav_tab_items() {
    $item_features         = array(
        'tab'     => 'features',
        'caption' => __( 'Features', 'textdomain' ),
        'content' => plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'admin/partials/settings-tab-features.php'
    );
    $item_setup     = array(
        'tab'     => 'setup',
        'caption' => __( 'Setup', 'textdomain' ),
        'content' => plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'admin/partials/settings-tab-setup.php'
    );


    $nav_tab_items = array();

    array_push( $nav_tab_items, $item_features );
    array_push( $nav_tab_items, $item_setup );


    //filter to hook new tabs for extra settings
    return apply_filters( 'settings_nav_tab_items', $nav_tab_items );
}
```

in another module when the module is activated i am trying to hook into the tabs and add a new settings tab for the module when activated.

I am calling this filter function:

```
add_filter( 'settings_nav_tab_items', 'add_announcement_settings_tab' );
```

The callback for this is this function:

```
function add_announcement_settings_tab( $nav_tab_items ) {


        $item_announcements    = array(
            'tab'     => 'announcements',
            'caption' => __( 'Announcments', 'textdomain' ),
            'content' => plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'admin/partials/settings-tab-announcments.php'
        );

        return $nav_tab_items;
    }
```

No extra tab is appearing when this is called. Am I completely off track here??

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

The reason it did not work is stupidly simple I am so annoyed!! lol

Becasue I am in OOP (object orientated) I had to add my callback into an array.

So from this:

```
add_filter( 'settings_nav_tab_items', 'add_announcement_settings_tab' );
```

To this:

```
add_filter( 'settings_nav_tab_items', array($this, 'add_announcement_settings_tab') );
```